# Camel-Quartz2 route restarting fails

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, jbossfuse, quartz-core

We are using Camel-Quartz2 version 2.12.0 with clustering environment everything is  working as excepted, but the issue was when I try to restart the bundle, camel routes are not starting, stating the below error.

> org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX ClusterManager: detected 1
>   failed or restarted instances. org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
>   ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "MACHINE-NAME"'s failed
>   in-progress jobs.

There is no exception in the log. Please advice to resolve this issue.

**Quartz2 cron**

```
quartz2://CNTR_TRIGGER/CNTR_UPDATE?job.name=containerUpdates&job.durability=true&deleteJob=true&stateful=true&cron=0/10+*+*+*+*+?
```

Comment: The question is tagged jbossfuse: which version are you using? Why don't you use the same camel-quartz2 version as Camel?

Comment: Try to restart the JVM

Comment: Sorry to mention the jbossfuse version, its **jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379** and we are using the same version of camel-quartz2 @Alessandro Da Rugna

Comment: I have tried this already, same issue @Claus Ibsen